# Stacked grouped histogram HighCharts graphs with dynamic data using ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, dynamic, highcharts, series

I'd like to make stacked&grouped histograms using HighCharts and ASP.NET MVC3.
I found this example on HighCharts' site: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped

I would use JSonResult in my controller. 
In particular, in above example, graph series are pre-defined in javascript, while I would dynamically create them with JSON.

Answer (score 1):

With [DonNet.Highcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) you can easily create Highcharts only on the server side. There is example with the stacked and grouped column. Here is the server side code:

```
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender" })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = new[] { "Apples", "Oranges", "Pears", "Grapes", "Bananas" } })
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis
                      {
                          AllowDecimals = false,
                          Min = 0,
                          Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Number of fruits" }
                      })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "TooltipFormatter" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions { Column = new PlotOptionsColumn { Stacking = Stackings.Normal } })
            .SetSeries(new[]
                       {
                           new Series
                           {
                               Name = "John",
                               Data = new Data(new object[] { 5, 3, 4, 7, 2 }),
                               Stack = "male"
                           },
                           new Series
                           {
                               Name = "Joe",
                               Data = new Data(new object[] { 3, 4, 4, 2, 5 }),
                               Stack = "male"
                           },
                           new Series
                           {
                               Name = "Jane",
                               Data = new Data(new object[] { 2, 5, 6, 2, 1 }),
                               Stack = "female"
                           },
                           new Series
                           {
                               Name = "Janet",
                               Data = new Data(new object[] { 3, 0, 4, 4, 3 }),
                               Stack = "female"
                           }
                       });
```

You can pass the data as you like.